# Array with a range of numbers as Initial Input

Tags: arrays, bash, range

How can I declare an array in bash, which contains integer numbers from 1 to 100? Consequently, the following command

```
echo  "${The_Array[@]}"
```

should gives the number 1 to 100 as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a The_Array=( $(for i in {1..100}; do echo $i; done) )
echo "${The_Array[@]}"
```

Comment: you can replace the `for` loop with `echo {1..100}`